# Running application (Eclipse) disappeared on Ubuntu Unity

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, ubuntu-unity

I was using Eclipse and it disappeared. I can see its running using ps command, but I cannot Alt-Tab (Switch) to it, and its missing on left bar.

Before restarting it (I will loose work :S) does anybody have a suggestion? (Even switching to running "hidden" process in another way than unity)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you didn't accidentally moved it to another workspace? 
You can use the key combination Super (Windows logo key) + S to view all of your workspaces at once.

Maybe you can --reset Unity and see if that's gonna help, but I wouldn't bet on it:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/unity.1.html

Good luck! Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

press `alt+F2` and run `unity -reset`